# Micronaut: BootstrapContext does not contain BootstrapPropertySourceLocator bean

Tags: micronaut

I am writing code to be able to hot reload properties from file. I took the kubernetes secrets from mounted volumes as a base in class (`KubernetesConfigurationClient`).

Now I have a class like:

```
@Singleton
@Requires(property = ConfigurationClient.ENABLED, value = StringUtils.TRUE, defaultValue = StringUtils.FALSE)
@BootstrapContextCompatible
public class MountedVolumeConfigurationClient implements ConfigurationClient {
```

And another:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(MountedVolumeConfiguration.PREFIX)
@BootstrapContextCompatible
public class MountedVolumeConfiguration {
```

My application.yml:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: micronaut-service
  server:
    port: 8080
```

My bootstrap.yml

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: micronaut-service
  config-client:
    enabled: true

poc:
  client:
    mounted-volumes:
      enabled: true
      config-map-paths:
        - /configmaps
      secret-paths:
        - /secrets
```

Now the code works fine if I have `implementation("io.micronaut.kubernetes:micronaut-kubernetes-discovery-client:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT")` in my gradle.build dependencies, however when I don't it doesn't load the Singleton bean.

I found that the cause lies in this piece of code in class `DefaultApplicationContext`:

```
        private BootstrapPropertySourceLocator resolveBootstrapPropertySourceLocator(String... environmentNames) {
            if (this.bootstrapPropertySourceLocator == null) {

                BootstrapApplicationContext bootstrapContext = new BootstrapApplicationContext(bootstrapEnvironment, environmentNames);
                bootstrapContext.start();
                if (bootstrapContext.containsBean(BootstrapPropertySourceLocator.class)) {
                    initializeTypeConverters(bootstrapContext);
                    bootstrapPropertySourceLocator = bootstrapContext.getBean(BootstrapPropertySourceLocator.class);
                } else {
                    bootstrapPropertySourceLocator = BootstrapPropertySourceLocator.EMPTY_LOCATOR;
                }
            }
            return this.bootstrapPropertySourceLocator;
        }
```

`if (bootstrapContext.containsBean(BootstrapPropertySourceLocator.class))` is true when I have micronaut-kubernetes-discovery-client in my dependencies and false when I don't have.

Some added context, I am trying to be able to hot reload both secrets and configmaps whenever they are mounted as a volume in kubernetes. Now micronaut only watches for configmap changes and can only read secrets from mounted volumes. I would like to be fully independent from the kubernetes API.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that I was missing this dependency: `io.micronaut:micronaut-discovery-client` when applying `io.micronaut.kubernetes:micronaut-kubernetes-discovery-client:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT` it includes that one as well.